# How to get confusion matrix with relative values from kNN models with more than two factor levels?

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, mlr3

I built a simple kNN model with the packages `mlr3` and `mlr3learners`, using the `diabetes` data set from the `mclust` package. I am trying to use the kNN model to predict the `class` category based on the three available numeric features (`glucose`,`insulin`,`sspg`), and evaluate it's performance using measures from the `mlr3measures` package and a confusion matrix as I am interesting in assessing whether some classes get misclassified more often than others. My question is how can I obtain a confusion matrix with relative values?

Using following code I get a confusion matrix with absolute values.

**Code Example**

```
# load packages
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners) # for classif.kknn
library(mlr3measures) # for confusion_matrix()
library(mclust) # for data(diabetes)

# load data
data(diabetes, package = "mclust")
diabetes <- as.data.table(diabetes)

# define task
diabetes_task <- as_task_classif(diabetes, 
                                 target = "class", 
                                 id = "diabetes")

# define ML algorithm
knn_model <- lrn('classif.kknn')

# partition data
splits <- partition(diabetes_task) 

# train model
knn_model$train(diabetes_task, 
                row_ids = splits$train)

# test model 
prediction <- knn_model$predict(diabetes_task, 
                                row_ids = splits$test)

# evaluate performance
prediction$confusion
```

**Confusion Matrix**

```
           truth
 response   Chemical Normal Overt
   Chemical       10      2     0
   Normal          2     23     0
   Overt           0      0    11
```

Instead of this matrix, I'd like to have a confusion matrix with relative values. I just found out that the `confusion_matrix()` function from the `mlr3measures` package includes an argument to get relative values (i.e., `relative = TRUE`), but this function only works when the truth and response labels have only two factors.  Apparently, this was rather straightforward to obtain in the old `mlr` package. Sorry, if the question is a little basic, but is there a simple way to obtain the relative values confusion matrix?

Comment: Do you just need to divide by the sum of values in the matrix?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you can simply divide by the sum of all values in the matrix:

```
prediction$confusion / sum(prediction$confusion)

          truth
response     Chemical     Normal      Overt
  Chemical 0.25000000 0.06250000 0.04166667
  Normal   0.00000000 0.45833333 0.00000000
  Overt    0.00000000 0.00000000 0.18750000
```